# Months and Days are not being translated

Tags: angularjs, express, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am trying to translate a FullCalendar using the language file included in the package. To make it simpler with angular, I use the plugin ui-calendar.

To do so, I imported the language script as described in the [doc](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/lang/) :

```
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
... //other includes generated by bower
<script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- FullCalendar language pack -->
<script src="bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/lang/fr-ca.js"></script>
```

However, the months and the days are not being translated. I did managed to translate the labels manually using the ["monthNames"](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/monthNames/), "dayNames", etc configs, but IMO that's ugly and it doesn't translate the ui.bootstrap.datepicker.

From what I understand, the problem is momentjs who wont take anything I give him. I tried to do a 'moment.lang('fr-ca')' but it doesn't do much. Anyone know a "Mickey Mouse trick" that could help to fix this issue?

> Note: ui-calendar uses the v 1.6 of fullcalendar which doesn't include the languages utilities. So I added fullcalendar@2.1.0 to my bower.json. Everything seams to be working properly, I don't see where this could mess up the language since I'm calling fullcalendar directly.

Comment: Please setup a plunkr or jsfiddle so I can help you in an efficient way

Comment: Sure! Sounds like a great opportunity to try out plunkr! I'll be right back!

Comment: So yeah, I've been working on the plunker. I managed to have a "working" prototype, however I can't fetch the proper versions of fullcalendar and ui-calendar from the plunker ui.

I tried to copy/paste all the scripts in plunker but ui-calendar would say fullCalendar does not exist.

To get it working, I have to use the version 1.6.1 of fullCalendar. Would that mean that in my app, even tho i try to force the version 2.1, it still uses the old one? Or am I messing the includes?

Here's the plunker if you want to play around: http://embed.plnkr.co/ECQWeo28oagCCo3935Cp/preview

Comment: Oh wait, I got it working with my scripts, you can see that the calendar controls are in french, yet the month labels and day labels are in english. Any idea? 
http://embed.plnkr.co/ECQWeo28oagCCo3935Cp/preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/AFpj79M1C6vOewSWLX8J

You also need to localise angular, you can read the doc here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n
To make it work I added the code of `i18n/angular-locale_fr-ca.js` in the plunkr file `ng-fr-ca.js`.

Looking at the source of ui-calendar (line 179), you will see it uses anggular `$locale` service to translate days, month, etc. I have added a `console.log` to the source so you can see the difference between

```
var dtf = $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS;
console.log(dtf);
```

`$locale` uses engglish by default. If you load one of the `i18n` locale file, you will have it translated.

Comment: Yay! That's exactly the magic trick I was looking for :D. Thanks for your help!